# Android-Click Part Of An Image

Tags: android, image, click

i want to create a clickable image. For example, if we think about world as an image and when a continent is clicked/selected, it will show its name in an alert box. I don't know how to do it can somebody help me? thanks

Comment: Your image is displayed by an ImageView? You know how to add an onClickListener to the view? Where do you need help exactly?

Comment: @greenapps I think he wants to have different things happen depending on where he clicks in the image, which can be done but likely won't be that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how precise you want to be but the simplest solution would be to have an ImageView of your world map inside of a relative layout. On top of which layer invisible Buttons using @android:color/transparent for the background property. Customise the width and height values manually with dp to get your desired size.

For this context of the problem, continent clicking, this should suffice.

Comment: When I click , I want to avoid touching on an empty area or other continent corner. How can I do that? @user1228602

Comment: You are going have to be careful with different screen sizes, but what you can do is extract the rough outline of the continent. Use those as the background for the button. Make sure your ImageView showing the whole world image is rendered last, bottom of xml, apply the button background in XML rather then in JAVA.